# Comparing two files linewise and if pattern of file 1 is not found (fully or partially) in file 2 then print line of file 1

Tags: awk, grep, bioinformatics, file-comparison, pattern-matching

I have two files:

file1 (search):

```
1  
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGTTTTTTTTT  
2  
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAAT  
3  
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGCGTCC  
4  
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCCGTCCGTAG
```

file2 (patterns):

```
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGC
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGCG
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGCGTCC
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGCGTCCGTAG
```

What I need is:

```
1  
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGTTTTTTTTT  
2  
3  
4  
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCCGTCCGTAG
```

Which means, that I need a script that searches my search-lines in the patterns-file, and if the search-lines can be found fully or partially (as for the line following "2") then they should not be written, but all other lines of file 1.

I tried many of the grep and awk scripts found in that forum but none did what I need, e.g.

```
awk 'FN==NR {exclude[$0];next} !($0 in exclude)' file2 file1
```

or

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next} !($1 in a) {print $1} {next}' file2 file1
```

I also tried grep.

Anyway, all tried scripts just find the fully matching patterns but not the partially matching ones...

Has anyone have an idea??

Comment: This looks like fasta files. How big are the files? This matters for the solution.  If there is too much data, you can't simply use the DNA as keys in an associative array.

Comment: One of the files is fasta format, the other one is text with each line having a different pattern. The file in fasta format is very large (130 million reads, 260 million lines), the pattern file contains 2000 different patterns.

Comment: Do the sequences in the fasta (search) file span multiple lines, or are they all short sequences on single lines?

Comment: The sequences in the fasta format are up to 260 characters (nucleotides) long.

Comment: Yes, but do they span multiple lines?

Comment: It's _really_ important that you show actual data. A fasta file's header lines are prefixed by `>`. Can you confirm that 1) yes, they have `>` at the start of the line, and 2) no sequence span multiple lines.

Comment: to 1) the fasta file starts with > but the test file not just starts with the numbers (I could have been more correct here, sorry) ; to 2) just one  sequence per line and no multiple lines

Answer (score 2):

Using an `awk` script:

```
NR == FNR       { seq[++n] = $1; next }

{
    header = $0
    getline

    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        if (match(seq[i], $0) > 0) {
            print header
            next
        }
    }

    print header
    print
}
```

Running it:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file2 file1
1
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGTTTTTTTTT
2
3
4
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCCGTCCGTAG
```

The script first reads the 2000 sequences from `file2` into the array `seq`, and then reads the header from `file1` followed by the sequence from `file1` (using `getline`).  It then goes through the array `seq` to find a sequence that contains the current sequence from `file1`.  If such a sequence is found, the header is printed and the script continues with the next line in `file1`. Otherwise, both header and sequence are printed.

The script assumes that the `file1` contains alternating header and sequence lines, and absolutely no multi-line sequence.

The following is the same script but using DRY principle ("Don't repeat yourself"):

```
NR == FNR       { seq[++n] = $1; next }

{
    header = $0
    getline

    found = 0
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        if (match(seq[i], $0) > 0) {
            found = 1
            break
        }
    }

    print header
    if (!found) print
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**`awk`** + **`grep`** solution:

```
awk '/^[^>0-9]/{ 
         m = ""; cmd = sprintf("grep -m1 %s file2", $0);
         cmd | getline m; close(cmd);
         if (m) next; 
     }1' file1
```

- `cmd` - crucial `grep` command
- `m` - variable filled with possible matched item

The output:

```
1
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGTTTTTTTTT
2
3
4
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCCGTCCGTAG
```

Comment: This results in the same results which I got with all other scripts before:

Comment: GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGTTTTTTTTT   
2    
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAAT  
3   
4    
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCCGTCCGTAG

Comment: @MSt, your block named *What I need is:* contains the output as this approach gives. Otherwise, you've posted non-actual data

Comment: ... the sequence after >2 is still in my output and needs to get removed as it is part of the pattern.

Comment: @MSt, *still in my output* - if your output differs from mine - then you did something wrong or posted non-actual data. The output I've posted is from a real test case

Comment: And I tried exactly your script with the above mentioned texts... strange

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest If this is a fasta file, then the header lines will not be just digits, but something like `>1`. With your `sprintf`, this will create a shell redirection. You're also doing one `grep` per each of the 130 million sequences.

Comment: @Kusalananda, if this is just about the format, see my update. Besides, the input should be extended in such case (the question should be updated)

Comment: I actually don't have any problem with the fasta header lines (and it doesn't matter right now whether it starts with > or just with digits). Which I don't get resolved is the problem that the second (character) sequence is not getting removed although the pattern is part of a pattern in the pattern file... and that's so strange...

Comment: @MSt I too tested Roman's code, and it worked here as he described it.

Comment: @Kusalananda You both are probably right. I tried it again and again, also with reentering the files as above, but anyway - my second sequence is still remaining... :-( ... as I'm using a putty shell for scripting... might that be a difference? (Although grep should work the same here or there...)  :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -vxf <(grep -of file_1 file_2 | sort -u) file_1
```

**file_1**

```
1
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGTTTTTTTTT
2
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAAT
3
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGCGTCC
4
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCCGTCCGTAG
```

**file_2**

```
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGC
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGCG
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGCGTCC
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGCGTCCGTAG
```

**Output**

```
1
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGTTTTTTTTT
2
3
4
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCCGTCCGTAG
```

Comment: I have no clue at all but I tried your and all other provided scripts on different computers but my output still looks like:  <br/> 1  <br/>
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGTTTTTTTTT <br/> 
2  <br/>
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAAT  <br/>
3  <br/>
4  <br/>
GACGGAGGATGCAAGTGTTATCCGGAATCACTGGGCCGTCCGTAG  <br/>?????????

Comment: @MSt Maybe because of `<br>` tag? They don't present in your sample files in the question, so you and we use different input for testing. Try to remove all tags before checking. The contents of the files should be exactly the same as in the question, then the proposed solutions should work correctly.